# How to alert an ampersand?

Tags: javascript

In my browser's Developer Tools console, I made the following attempts to display an ampersand in an alert prompt:

```
alert('&'); // displays nothing
alert('\&'); // displays nothing
alert('&amp;'); // displays amp;
var a = '&';
a
"&" // console output
alert(a); // displays nothing
```

What is so special about an ampersand in an alert prompt, and how to display it?

Browser in question is Opera 20.

Comment: `alert('&');` works for me in Firefox.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you alert `&&`?

Comment: Worked for me in Chrome, FF and IE.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol it alerts `&`, a single ampersand

Comment: How about: alert('\u0026'); (I don't have Opera to test right now).

Comment: @zvona the alert displays nothing

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol this displays && on Chrome and FF.

Comment: Opera 20 on windows 7 alert('&') returns &...

Comment: @kennebec thanks, it seems to only happen on OSX

Comment: @Howard- good to know, sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript replace function:

```
alert('&amp;'.replace(/&amp;/g, '&'));
```

The 'g' modifier is used to perform a global match on the string (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).